# Travelling wave solutions of the Tzitzeica–Dodd–Bullough equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transformation, wave-equation

I have been spending time with the Tzitzeica equation, the travelling-wave solution of which is troubling me (in particular the ansatz given in Equation $(5)$):

For $u=u(x, t)$
\begin{equation}
u_{xt} = e^{-u}+e^{-2u} \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Under the transformation $v(x, t)=e^{-u}$ one obtains
\begin{align}
v = e^{-u} &\iff - \ln v = u \\
\implies u_t &= -\frac{v_t}{v} \\ \tag{2}
\text{and}\, u_{tx} &= \frac{-v_{tx}v+v_{t}v_{x}}{v^{2}} 
\end{align} 
Inserting $(2)$ into $(1)$ we obtain
\begin{align}
-v_{tx}v - v_t v_x &= v^{2} \left( e^{-u}-e^{-2u}\right) \\
\iff 0 &= vv_{xt}-v_t v_x+v^{3}+v^{4} \tag{3}
\end{align}

For so-called *travelling-wave* solutions set (into $(3)$)
$$v=v(x, t), \qquad \xi=x-wt, \qquad v(x,t) = v(\xi)$$
to obtain
\begin{equation}
-wvv''+w(v')^2 + v^3 +v^4=0 \tag{4}
\end{equation}

Now, the travelling-wave transformation above allows us to write solutions in the form
$$v(\xi) = \sum_{k=0}^{N} A_k \left( \frac{\psi'(\xi)}{\psi( \xi)}\right) \tag{5}$$
Where the $A_k\, (k = 0,1,2,3,\ldots)$ are arbitrary constants to be determined and $\psi$ is an as yet undetermined function.

It is at this point that I cannot seem to progress other that inputting $(5)$ into $(4)$ and trying to determine the values of the $A_k$.

I owuld have thought that I could determine $N$ from the ansatz in $(5)$ to get a simpler solution.

Am I correct in thinking this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a typo. The Tzitzeica-Bullough-Dodd equation is $u_{xt} = e^{u} - e^{-2u}$, according to this reference (eqn 2.9)

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.5517.pdf

Travelling wave solutions of the equation in your post may be found explicitly. Look for $u(x,t) = U(x-ct)$. Then
$$
-cU'' = e^{-U} + e^{-2U}
$$
and the general solutions are
$$
\begin{align}
U_1(\xi) &= \log \left(\frac{e^{-\sqrt{A} \xi } \left(-A c+2
   e^{\sqrt{A} \xi }-e^{2 \sqrt{A} \xi
   }-1\right)}{2 A c}\right)\\
U_2(\xi) &= \log \left(\frac{-A c e^{\sqrt{A} \xi
   }-e^{-\sqrt{A} \xi }-e^{\sqrt{A} \xi }+2}{2 A
   c}\right)
\end{align} 
$$
where $A$ is a constant and $c$ is the wave speed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, there is no typo, I should have made it clear this is the Tzitzeica–Dodd–Bullough equation. Let me digest your efforts here, thansk again.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Terrific push in your answer, i see that I can just re-write as you did in your second paragraph. Thanks!